# How to disable AWS Global Accelerator Flow Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-global-accelerator

I recently enabled flow logs for global accelerator to troubleshoot an issue. below is the AWS CLI command i ran to enable flowlogs for global accelerator as per aws article.

```
aws globalaccelerator update-accelerator-attributes 
       --accelerator-arn arn:aws:globalaccelerator::012345678901:accelerator/1234abcd-abcd-1234-abcd-1234abcdefgh 
       --region us-west-2
       --flow-logs-enabled
       --flow-logs-s3-bucket s3-bucket-name 
       --flow-logs-s3-prefix s3-bucket-prefix
```

My S3 bucket is getting huge with the GA flow logs and I no longer need these logs, I would like to disable the flow logs for global accelerator and I don't find a working aws cli command to disable the flow logs for global accelerator. `--flow-logs-disabled` doesnt exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you are looking for is:

```
--no-flow-logs-enabled
```

So your commandline would become:

```
aws globalaccelerator update-accelerator-attributes 
   --accelerator-arn arn:aws:globalaccelerator::012345678901:accelerator/1234abcd-abcd-1234-abcd-1234abcdefgh 
   --region us-west-2
   --no-flow-logs-enabled
```

See the documentation for details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/globalaccelerator/update-accelerator-attributes.html